# @font-face problems between strong tag and faux bold rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

My website is set in Avenir Medium via @font-face as seen below :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir-Medium";
    src: url("/Shared/fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf") format('truetype'), 
    url("/Shared/fonts/Avenir-Medium.woff") format('woff');
}
```

I am applying this via the body like :

```
body {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.25em; 
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    font-family: "Avenir-Medium", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

This is pulling in the proper font for the body just fine. However, `<strong>` tags look horrible on a PC (Chrome, FireFox, IE, etc) due to faux bold rendering. At this point I decided I needed to pull in the italic/heavy versions of Avenir :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir-Heavy";
    src: url("/Shared/fonts/Avenir-Heavy.ttf") format('truetype'), 
    url("/Shared/fonts/Avenir-Heavy.woff") format('woff');
}

@font-face {
   font-family: "Avenir-MediumOblique";
   src: url("/Shared/fonts/Avenir-MediumOblique.ttf") format('truetype'), 
   url("/Shared/fonts/Avenir-MediumOblique.woff") format('woff');
}
```

After these were pulling in properly, I made the following CSS rules :

```
strong {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "Avenir-Heavy", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}


em { 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "Avenir-MediumOblique", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

This is where my problem lies. On a Mac, the proper fonts are being pulled in for any `<strong>` and `<em>` declarations. On a PC though...faux rendering seems to be rearing it's ugly head. Bolded fonts look horrible now even though the browser SAYS it's pulling in Avenir-Heavy for `<strong>` declarations.

You can view an example of this issue [here](http://matthewgoddard.com/font-face/).

Comment: Try change `font-weight:700` on the font-face for the bold version

Comment: Where do these font files come from?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela We are hosting them on our server. Ideally I'd like something on a cdn like google/typekit but not an option right now with this font. :/

Comment: @Danko Will definitely try that when I am back in the office. I wasn't having much luck with font-weight: 700 or 800 though. Will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: You need to *identify* the font you are using, in a manner that lets others test it, show a minimal document that actually demonstrates the issue, and clearly state what the issue is in directly observable terms. “Faux rendering” is a conclusion from something, not an observation. It is difficult to see why faux bold would be used *if* `font-weight: normal` applies to the element.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the suggestions. I've setup an example of what I am working with here :

[link](http://matthewgoddard.com/font-face/)

The `<strong>` tag embedded in the paragraph is supposed to be loading in Avenier-Heavy. It appears this is happening but on a PC the rendered font is jagged and rough looking.

Comment: You are supposed to clarify the question by editing the question, not in comments, and to provide relevant code *in the question itself*. Information about the font includes its source and the method of generating the font files. And “jagged” is not a problem description. This issue may simply boil down to the font rendering differences. But the link given opens in my Firefox so that Avenir Medium and Avenir Heavy are used, so what is thing thing about “faux bold”?

Comment: This is obviously the first time I've used this site. Which I am now second guessing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link very useful when I ran into a similar problem regarding the use of a google font "Alegreya SC" bold, normaL AND italic.

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

According to that site i used font squirrel to create a few more font formats and came up with a bullet-proofed version that went like this

```
 @font-face {
            font-family:alegreyareg;
            src: url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.svg#svgFontName) format('svg');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:alegreyabold;
            src: url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-bold-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-bold-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-bold-webfont.svg#svgFontName) format('svg');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:alegreyaital;
            src: url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-italic-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-italic-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
                 url(webfontkit/alegreyasc-italic-webfont.svg#svgFontName) format('svg');
        }
```

This seemed to work for me. Hope this helps you as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I went through this process today but received an error stating the Linotype foundry has asked font squirrel not to allow Avenir (and other fonts they offer) to be converted into other formats. And it's unfortunately not a Google Font, we're hosting the ttf and woff files. Thanks again though.

Comment: If possible try to search for a google or open source font that is similar to Avenir. I had that problem as well lol. My client wanted a font that was proprietary to Adobe hence I researched the font world and came up with Alegreya which was very close to the original font. Thankfully the client was okay with the substitution.